# Editing a Question that gets Approved, Rejected and Edited all at once

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have just been rejected an [edit suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32286), that was:

- approved by [slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm)
- rejected by [community](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)
- edited by [Anthon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/33055/anthon)

The edit, was more or less what I suggested.

So why was it rejected then?

Why was it not approved and edited afterwards?

Comment: I looked up Xfce to make sure it is written that way on the official site (it looked wrong, but I was not sure). I know the OP had one XFCE wrong as well and you might have tried to make things consistent). SSH is inappropriate and IMHO worse than ssh. If I only  change additional things I would have left the helpful mark, but if I have to change things back because they became worse (IHMO) I unmark helpful and hope the editor notices and learns (which obviously worked). Sorry for the 2 points missed. If you mentioned @Anthon in the chat I might have noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewers of suggested edits can choose between four possibilities:

- Approve (takes effect if 2 reviewers choose this option)
- Reject (takes effect if 2 reviewers choose this option)
- Skip
- Edit, which opens the editor on the message. When the reviewer submits his edit, it becomes the new revision of the message. There is an additional checkbox “suggested edit was helpful”, which is checked by default.

  - If the reviewer leaves the “helpful” box checked, the suggested edit appears in the post's revision history and is marked as approved by the Community user.
  - If the reviewer unchecks the “helpful” box, the suggested edit does not appear in the post's revision history and is marked as rejected by the Community user.

Reviewers uncheck the “helpful” box when they decide that there was something to edit in the post but the edit was not good, either because some changes were bad or because the edit was too minor.

It's also possible for an edit to be rejected by Community if someone else with edit privileges happens to edit at the same time: the direct edit wins over the suggested edit.

---

In this specific case, you did well to lowercase the all-caps fragment and to add the keyboard formatting, but you also used code markup on proper names. I think I've rejected some of your edits for that reason too. Code markup is not for proper names, it's for code. Code markup is only for things that you would type — shell commands, file contents, etc. Proper names such as XFCE or SSH are written with an initial capital letter, or in all caps when they are initialisms, or sometimes in weirder ways, but never as code. SSH is the name of the protocol and of the application; `ssh` is the command to start the application. `SSH` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

Very lazy answer, copying & pasting from [Unix & Linux chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12469307#12469307):

> Kevdog777
>   @slm, hey. I have just asked a question why my edit suggestion was rejected after it was approved, rejected and edited all at once. meta.unix.stackexchange.com/…
>   Really confusing
>
> derobert
>   @Kevdog777 well, the simple answer is Anthon unchecked the 'suggested edit was helpful' box
>
> Kevdog777
>   @derobert If he did check the box, could he still have edited it again afterwards?
>
> derobert
>   When you have enough rep on the site (I forget how much exactly, 3k or 5k, probably), you get three options when reviewing suggested edits: approve, reject, improve
>   If you click improve, it lets you edit the question/answer, starting with the suggested edit as a base
>   There is a checkbox on that page for whether the suggested edit was helpful or not
>   If you leave it checked, Community will approve the suggested edit. If you uncheck it, Community rejects the suggested edit.
>   Either way, your improved edit shows after that.

Comment: The box is checked by default. Your message gives the opposite impression.

Comment: @Gilles Fixed. Should now be clear its checked by default.