# What to do with mediocre edits with "blah blah" edit message?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

In review I came across a suggested edit for this question:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331202/135943

The proposed edit ain't bad, just a tiny bit of grammar and wording cleanup.  It's not a totally trivial edit, but not a major copy-edit job either.  (As I said, mediocre.)

I would have clicked "approve" except I really don't want to encourage the laziness and sloppiness of including the edit message, "Improve blah blah."

I found this related meta post:

- [What is the best way to improve the edits made by a suggested editor](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2748/135943)

But, I haven't seen a post that discussed acceptable *edits* with a sloppy or uninformative *edit message.*

What are the options?  What do *you* think should be done in such a case?

Comment: I had to check whether you said "blah blah" or the edit message.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming that the suggested edit is good enough
that you would consider accepting it, based on its own merits,
and ignoring the comment, here’s a possible approach:

The first time you see something like this:

1. Accept the edit (or improve it).
2. Leave a comment for the editor asking him to write better comments. 
   (You can @-ping people who have (successfully) edited a post. 
   But you’ll have to type (or copy and paste) the user’s name,
   because it isn’t included in the auto-complete. 
   And this doesn’t work at all for users
   who have suggested edits that were rejected.)
3. Make a note of the user name.

Then, when you see more low-quality edit comments coming from the same users,
reject them.

Comment: Thanks for the information in Point 2. The UI for SE sites is excellent so I concluded from the lack of auto-completion that it wasn't possible to notify an editor with a comment.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan you may want to vote and comment on [this meta proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106534/307622).